# NServiceBus Reply Message warning

Tags: nservicebus

I have an ASP.Net WebAPI application that uses NServiceBus.  Commands are sent from the application to a back end server that is running the NSB host.  The server is responsible for communication with the database.

Most commands are fire-and-forget.  A simple Bus.Send(...) and the web client is released immediately so the operation can happen asynchronously.

The exception is for commands that create new records in the database.  The database is responsible for generating the ID of the newly created entity, and I need to return that back to the caller.  This is less performant because the caller has to stick around, but it is an acceptable hit in my situation.

I am successfully using the Bus.Reply() feature for this, as documented in the Full Duplex samples.  I'm replying with a message that has a single property for the newly generated Id.  On the web side, I have registered the callback with a task continuation (taking advantage of WebAPI's async ability), and using .Register following Bus.Send().

This is all working just fine.  It accomplishes exactly what I want, in a very straightforward and easy way.  The only problem is that every time a response message is received by the client, it logs a warning as follows:

```
2012-09-11 16:46:44,745 [Worker.26] WARN  NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.Transactional.TransactionalTransport [(null)] - Failed raising 'transport message received' event for message with ID=1faee572-f904-4b09-b1d5-c0bd7c12738d\82936
System.InvalidOperationException: No handlers could be found for message type: MyProject.Messages.MyEntityCreatedResponseMessage
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.HandleTransportMessage(IBuilder childBuilder, TransportMessage msg)
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.TransportMessageReceived(Object sender, TransportMessageReceivedEventArgs e)
   at System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e)
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.Transactional.TransactionalTransport.OnTransportMessageReceived(TransportMessage msg)
```

How can I get rid of this warning?  I don't need a message handler here.

Comment: Off the top of my head - I think you need to implement a dummy (empty) handler. Otherwise, your MyEntityCreatedResponseMessage events will end up in the error queue

Comment: A dummy handler stops the warning, but then I get a different warning saying that I'm doing pub/sub without events...  Why does it think the .Reply is to be handled as if I did a .Publish??

Comment: I found that if I use Bus.Return instead of Bus.Reply, that I can accomplish what I was after without any error or warning.  However, this only works because I am treating the new ID as if it was an ErrorCode and my IDs happen to be integers.  If I needed to pass IDs of a different type, or any additional information (like an actual error code), then this wouldn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest creating the id either on the server or even the client (browser). That way your message can still be fire-and-forget and you don't need to synchronise anything.

If you want to persist with database driven ids, NServiceBus is only adding overhead. May as well talk directly to the database from your website code and add retries there.

Comment: That would require something like GUID identifiers.  I'd like to stick with a simple auto-incrementing integer if possible.  Writing directly to the DB instead of going through the bus would be an option, but it would bypass the rest of my architecture, so I'm not sure if I want to go that route.  Really, I just want the reply message to not require a handler.

Comment: Nothing says the GUID has to be used for persisting the entity to the database. All the GUID needs to be for is identifying the message used to persist the entity and correlating the reply. In that case, the GUID would be creates by the client.

Comment: @Matt, you don't have to use the same architecture for the entire project (or system). If the architecture is getting in the way of an optimal solution, then it's the wrong architecture.
Just think about what happens during that synchronous call. Web request arrives, gets converted  to MSMQ message, message is processed, reply gets converted to MSMQ message, dummy message arrives and is processed, reply is then sent back to web client.
All this overhead, what's the benefit of it?

Comment: @Rich, I was actually suggesting something like a Guid. And making the message truely fire-and-forget. Something that the client (or server) can fake the reply to the user.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the answer, because ultimately this yields a better solution.  Also, I found a way to generate my ids on the front end, so I don't need this afterall.

Comment: Just FYI, we'll support this in the future even though it's not recommended - https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus/issues/647